# Drupal 8 CKeditor behaves LTR in an RTL site

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I've installed Drupal 8.0.2 in a **standard** installation process and in **English**.

I later changed The site's default language to Hebrew (Which is an RTL language) and my content type is now setted to the site's default language - Hebrew. I even determined my user's administration account, called "admin", to Hebrew (a new Drupal 8 feature that let's you pick a specific front-end language to a certain user).

After that I've organized the CKeditor full-profile edit-bar in an RTL manner at it's configuration page (and flushed all caches afterwards):

[image]

---

### You saw - I did everything by the book, and yet:

I encounter two issues that comprise my whole problem:

**1.** The CKeditor edit-bar appears the opposite from how I arranged it (as can be seen one image up).

[image]

**2.** CKeditor input area [typing cursor](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=Writing%20cursor&biw=1920&bih=916&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMo_O-o5nKAhUB2xoKHVPQBaAQ_AUIBigA&dpr=1#q=typing%20cursor) starts in the left instead of the right (I could easily manually flip the Edit-bar but the cursor will still appear in the left).

[image]

When I installed a test site in Hebrew **from the start** (instead of installing first in English and then add Hebrew and make it default), I didn't encounter that problem, and the edit-bar was RTL. I have no clue how to explain this! Maybe you can!

Comment: I do not understand your first question, for second question, may be this link is helpful, http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/SOLVED-How-set-cursor-position-CKEditor

Comment: also, for CKEditor, you can press right CTRL+Shift, to move cursor to right side

Comment: 1. I edited the question (paragraph1). 2. As I already mentioned in the question - Right Ctrl + Shift doesn't move the cursor to the right.

Comment: BTW about the link you gave - Do you know what file it is? I understand it's a function named getAscendant but in what file is it?

Comment: Note that @benos has cross-posted this to the Drupal 8 core issue queue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2646434

Comment: Hello @WimLeers I replied to you in the issue: I kept trying many things in the last 24 hours but nothing helps with this problem. The front-end just won't changed. Not in CKeditor at least.

Comment: I am now offering 100 rep bounty. Based on the information in both places I suggest you would write a working answer; I will also gladly accept and thumb up.

Comment: It seems to be a minor problem in the language system architecture of Drupal 8... The maintainers are now discussing how to fix this... [Here is a link to the discussion](https://www.drupal.org/node/2646434).

Answer (score 13):

The default CKEditor text language direction is LTR.
To change it to RTL, you can try setting the JS config setting:

```
config.contentsLangDirection = 'rtl';
```

Reference: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.contentsLangDirection

In D7, there was a config textarea that can be set:

[image: ckeditor.config.rtl]

In D8, you can set the CKEditor config settings in:

[`hook_editor_js_settings_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!editor!editor.api.php/function/hook_editor_js_settings_alter/8)

Something like:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_editor_js_settings_alter
 */
function MYMODULE_editor_js_settings_alter(array &$settings) {
  foreach ($settings['editor']['formats'] as $name => $value) {
    $settings['editor']['formats'][$name]['editorSettings']['contentsLangDirection'] = 'rtl';
  }
}
```

More info on creating Drupal 8 modules here: https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/8

You can also set the config in JS, for example your theme

Something like:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.customCKEditorConfig = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      if (typeof CKEDITOR !== "undefined") {
        CKEDITOR.config.contentsLangDirection = 'rtl';
      }
    }
  }
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

More info on adding theme assets here: https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/assets

For your other question on the toolbar button ordering. That appears to work, just make sure you set the toolbar button order on all the "Text formats" that you want to use it with (e.g "Basic HTML", "Restricted HTML" and "Full HTML") in the CKEditor admin settings.

[image: Sample RTL CKEditor input]

Comment: Where have you seen this in Drupal 8? I know this conf session from Drupal 7 but not Drupal 8...

Comment: @benos, updated for D8 CKEditor option.

Comment: Much thanks to you David Tohmas! Even though I did some theming and can understand a small bit of basic PHP code (at least in logic) I am just starting to learn PHP and I don't know what I should do with that hook\core-manipulation... I mean, I don't know how to actually run it. Can you please detail just a bit more where to paste it? Just some preliminary information for people like me which just start to taste this world

Comment: @benos, you're welcome. I updated my answer with another option to set the config using JS. It also includes drupal.org links on module and theme development for reference there. I tested both approaches and they work to set the CKEditor text input to RTL. Wishing you a great 2016.

Comment: Fine year with much happiness, good deeds, and prosperity to all of us amen,

Comment: Thank you David, I was able to get the text to go 'rtl' using your hook_editor_js_settings_alter. Now a am trying to use the feature config.disallowedContent  examples here: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_disallowed_content.html. I modified your hook and this is working for me.    $settings['editor']['formats'][$name]['editorSettings']['disallowedContent'] = 'h1';

Answer (score 2):

Also [CKEditor BiDi Buttons](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_bidi) module provides the bi directional text flow buttons, RTL and LTR.

> Integrates the [CKEditor BiDi plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/bidi) with CKEditor for Drupal 8.
>   This plugin provides the bi directional text flow buttons, RTL and LTR
>   .
>
> The CKEditor BiDi plugin makes it possible to change the text
>   direction for an HTML block-level elements like paragraphs and lists.
>   This ability is essential for authoring content in languages that are
>   written Right to Left like those with Arabic and , Hebrew writing
>   systems.