# Drupal.behaviors.customCKEditorConfig

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I am trying to use the Disallowed Content configuration from Ckeditor.
https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_disallowed_content.html
I am using Drupal 8.5.3 Lightning 8.x-3 and the built in Ckeditor v4.8

I have placed this js in my theme and the js is loading when I am in page edit mode.

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.customCKEditorConfig = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      if (typeof CKEDITOR !== "undefined") {
        config.disallowedContent= 'div span';
      }
    }
  }
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

But this is not working. I have tried with the Allowed HTML tags enabled and disabled. I got this information from these sources. http://drucafe.blogspot.com/2016/02/adding-custom-styles-to-ckeditor-in.html
and https://tutel.me/c/drupal/questions/183036/allow+empty+tags and [Drupal 8 CKeditor behaves LTR in an RTL site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186102/drupal-8-ckeditor-behaves-ltr-in-an-rtl-site/186303#186303).

I have tried the filter 3 different ways

```
editor.filter.disallow( 'span div' );
config.disallowedContent( 'span div' );
config.disallowedContent= 'div span';
```

Comment: Are there any console errors?

Comment: No I dont have any console errors. I am just using Seven as the admin theme so I place my js file inside seven and added it to the library. The js is loaded. I am using Drupal 8.5.3 Lightning 8.x-3 and the built in Ckeditor v4.8. I have tried the filter 3 different ways.    editor.filter.disallow( 'span div' );
config.disallowedContent( 'span div' );
config.disallowedContent= 'div span';

Comment: I read that disallowedContent supersedes allowed content. And if the Advanced Content Filter is disabled than disallowedContent will not work. I dont know how to check if Advanced Content Filter is enabled.

Comment: You should definitely have at least one console error. You don’t have a variable named `config` in scope in your code example

Comment: I just noticed a console error: ReferenceError: config is not defined

Comment: I thought config is something thats defined in Ckeditor. When looking at their first example on this page: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_disallowed_content.html

Comment: I changed it to this and I don't get the error, but it doesn't work. CKEDITOR.config.disallowedContent = 'h2 h3 h4';

Comment: Thats the wrong scope - I think what you are looking for is either in `settings` or `drupalSettings`. Like Clive said, you are referring to a variable that doesn't even exist (`config`). You need to drill down and find the correct scope - you can't just guess with javascript. It does not matter what is defined in _other_ scopes or JS files - if the scope/variable(s) are not passed in to a function you cannot reference it. Therefore you need to reference the source and not _other_ variables in other js files.

Comment: Thank for your help. I updated my post. I got it to work by using hook_editor_js_settings_alter

Comment: Please don't add answers to questions - you can answer your own question below. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is working.

```
use Drupal\editor\Entity\Editor;

function MYMODULE_editor_js_settings_alter(array &$settings) {
  foreach ($settings['editor']['formats'] as $name => $value) {
    $settings['editor']['formats'][$name]['editorSettings']['disallowedContent'] =   
'h1 h2 h3';
  }
}
```

This supersedes any allowed tags in the drupal GUI. But you must enable Allowed HTML tags enabled for this to work. I took the idea from this.[drupal-8-ckeditor-behaves-ltr](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186102/drupal-8-ckeditor-behaves-ltr-in-%20%20an-rtl-site/186303#186303)